# MySQL Pivot table Query in dynamic rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. Just like

```
----UserTable---- 
id  user    email       
1   admin   admin@gmail.com
2   editor  editor@gmail.com

----NameTable---- 
name    userid  fullname    mobile
own         1   Rahim       012314
father      1   Karim       120120
mother      1   Florin      212021
own         2   Masum       012314
father      2   Nahid       120120
mother      2   Zane        212021
```

How to fetch data all (Just Like name, Father, Mother, Own name) data in single query in mysql?

```
----Output Table----
id  user    email               name        fathername  mothername
1   admin   admin@gmail.com     Rahim       Karim       Florin
2   editor  editor@gmail.com    Masum       Nahid       Zane
```

Comment: Use Sql Inner Join http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Kindly give me a query for this? I am new learner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to use pivot in case there are always maximum of 3 columns(own,father and mother in this case)

```
SELECT t.id,t.user,t.email,
       max(case when s.name = 'own' then s.fullname end) as name,
       max(case when s.name = 'father' then s.fullname end) as fathername,
       max(case when s.name = 'mother' then s.fullname end) as mothername
FROM UserTable t
INNER JOIN NameTable s ON(t.id = s.user_id)
```